# Getting selected text and saving its position to the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following javascript code to get the selected text:

```
function getSelected() {

    if(window.getSelection){ 

        return window.getSelection(); 
    }

    else if(document.getSelection){ 

        return document.getSelection(); 
    }
    else{

        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();

        if(selection.text) { 

            return selection.text; 
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This successfully extracts the selected text. How do I get the position of the selected text and pass it to another django view and save it to the database so that I can retrieve it later.

By position I mean any indication as to where the selected text starts and ends. I have tried regex search and failed. For example. If the page contains the following text:

```
the page contains text that the page should contain.
```

And the selection is the second 'page', how do I retrieve that and pass it on. Can I serialize all the text in a page to an array and retrieve the exact position of the selected text? How?

Comment: Hmm, this may differ between browsers, but, you can use `baseOffset` to get the start of the caret selection and `extentOffset` to get the end of the caret position in chrome, for instance. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usmk883u/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Works ok for normal selections but in case of a double click select doesn't work.